# sumar datos de una tabla con php. el codigo que genere me dice cuantas filas tiene la tabla, pero quiero que me sume los datos que hay en ella

Tags: php

```php
echo '<table>';
    
$resultadoPO =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
$resultadoPY =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
$resultadoRG =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
$resultadoRU =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
    
for($fila =2; $fila<= $highestRow; $fila++){
       
}
```

este es el resultado del codigo, en la parte que totaliza me suma el numero de filas y lo que necesito es que me sume los datos que hay en cada fila.

agradezco su ayuda.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Por favor realiza el [tour] y lee [ask] y agrega un [example] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La manera mas sencilla es hacerlo a través de un contador antes de ingresar a tu ciclo For debes setear una variable en =0; y luego poner el contador dentro del ciclo For la cual irá acumulando el valor que le asignes.

```php
$cont = 0; 
for($fila =2; $fila<= $highestRow; $fila++){
$cont = $cont + $variable;     
}
```

Una vez finalizado el for tu variable $cont tendrá la suma de todos los datos,
solo deberás hacer un echo en donde corresponda.

Comment: me podrias aclarar la formula ya que al digitarla, no suma los datos correspondientes.  el codigo es el siguiente. $resultadoPO =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
$resultadoPY =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
$resultadoRG =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
$resultadoRU =$sheet-> getHighestRow(0);
    
$cont =0;

for($fila =2; $fila<= $highestRow; $fila++){
$cont = $cont+  $resultadoPO;     
}
ECHO " EL RESULTADO ES $cont"

Comment: Lo mas probable es que tu variable ``$resultadoPO;`` sea un objeto, con lo cual tendrá algunas propiedades y valores implícitos a los cuales debes acceder directamente, intenta haciendo un ``var_dump($resultadoPO);``  para ver su estructura y puedas ver en que atributo se encuentra el valor que buscas.